# Pinch gesture and single touch

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, gesture

I have a couple of questions,
1) I have a UIImageView control on a view. I would like to add the pinch gesture to allow zooming in and out.
2) I have the requirement to drop additional images on top of the base image, these images do not need to zoom, but they will need to remain in the original location that they were placed on the base image.

Now the question is this....
How do I test for a single touch and drag around, while also looking for a pinch and stretch gesture for the base image?

Thanks for everyone helps on this.

take care
tony

Answer (score 0):

Add this in viewdidload:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];  //imageView is your base image 
    [pinchGesture release];




//Zooming of image
-(IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender
{

    if (pictureTimer) {  //This is NSTimer. set pictureTimer=1 in viewdidLoad
        return;
    }


    CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender scale];
    if(factor >1)
    {
        sender.view.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor +(factor-1), lastScaleFactor +(factor-1));
    }
    else {
        sender.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor * factor, lastScaleFactor*factor);
    }

    if (sender.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (factor>1) {
            lastScaleFactor +=(factor-1);
        }
        else {
            lastScaleFactor*= factor;
        }

    }

}
```

Your will get stretch to your base image.